# return a value from this variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This has been driving me crazy.. I am trying to return a value from a variable and I can't seem to do it.  When I multiply the variable by something, it works fine, but when I try to just show that one variable on a keyup function, it's a no go.

This is the problem in the script I am running into:

```
$("input.numberOfAccounts").keyup(function () {
$("input.pricingPerAccount").val($(newPricePerAccount));
 });
```

As you can see, newPricePerAccount is the value I want to return and I have tried everything to make it just return that.  What am I doing wrong?

Here it is in a jsfiddle, it will give you more insight.

http://jsfiddle.net/GLnQx/

EDIT:  I have updated the fiddle.. All I am really trying to do is match input.pricingPerAccount to the variable of newPricePerAccount and it keeps returning just object, object.  What's wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "return a value from a variable"--do you mean you're trying to set `pricingPerAccount`'s input to the number of accounts * `newPricePerAccount`?

Comment: This test works http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/pxZ6V/

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @elclanrs that's not what I am trying to do.. I am simply trying to match the newPricePerAccount variable to the input.pricingPerAccount...  newPricePerAccount variable runs through a huge if statement and gives me a value that I am trying to put in the input, as you can see from the fiddle I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/GLnQx/2/

EDIT:

If I understand your comment correctly, you want to re-update the value of `newPricePerAccount` each time as well? Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/GLnQx/6/

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted.. But why did the keyup stop working?  It only works one time and then stops updating the input under it?

Comment: If I could give this 100 gold stars I would.  Bravo.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var newPricePerAccount = $("input.pricingPerAccount").val() * $("input.numberOfAccounts").val();
    alert(newPricePerAccount);
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am just trying to match the the pricingPerAccount input to the newPricePerAccount upon keyup.  I am not trying to multiply it by anything.. That was just there to show that it works.